# calling by reference a variable which was called by reference by another function without using global var

Tags: c

I don't get this part. How can I do it if I'm not allowed to use global variables? Example:

```
main()
{ int z;
  function1(&z);
}

function1(int *x)
{
  function2(&x);
}

function2(int *number)
{
   ++(*number);
}
```

Comment: I don't see global variables here. And I don't get the question

Comment: no i mean, that code doesnt work. Wth is wrong with it?

Comment: its supposed to be an alternative to, declaring int z as a global variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `function1` calls `function2`, just pass in `x`, not `&x`.

```
function1(int *x)
{
  function2(x); /* not &x */
}
```

`&x` will pass `function2` a pointer to a pointer to an `int`, but it is declared to only take a pointer to an `int`.

Other issues: `z` should be initialized, and the functions should either have forward declarations, are declared above `main`. `main` should be declared to return an `int`, and return `0` on success. And as noted in the other answer, your other functions also need return types.

```
void function2(int *number)
{
   ++(*number);
}

void function1(int *x)
{
  function2(x);
}

int main()
{
  int z = 0;
  function1(&z);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: it gives out the error: passing an argument from integer to pointer without a cast